# with this function "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem and I do not know where I can solve everything I did because the error is in this $.ajax, 
because I have used this code several times before already looked and I have already reviewed and I did not get results and I went down to post here for you to help me

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$("#doarBronze").click(function()
{      
   $("#formVIP_Modal").modal("show"); 

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "bronze_doar_modal.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},

    success: function(data)
  {


            if(data.hasError == false)
            {          
                $("#abrir_vips_box").html(data.html);

                    $("#proxima_ir_cadastro_bronze").click(function()
                    {      

                      $("#abrir_vips_box").html(data.boxBronze_cadastro);
                      $("#TitleVips").html("Cadastro para o PainelVIP");

                    });

            }
            else{
                alert("ERRO!\n"+data.msgErro);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Ocorreu Um Erro Contate um Admistrador");
        }

    });
});


});
```

Comment: post html code please

Comment: Probably loading a *"slim"* version of jQuery in page that doesn't include $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require "insane.php";
$insane = new insane();

$html = '
<div id="infoBronze">
<center><b>Termos do Servidor </b><br></center>
Vantagens Extras <br>
<small>* Eventos Exclusivos Para Vip </small><br>
<small>* Suporte Exclusivo </small><br>
<small>* Sala no TS³</small><br><br>
Informacoes <br>
<small>* Reembolso de VIP Somente Quando Servidor Fechar/Falir. </small><br>
<small>* VIP Podem Ser Pausado Apenas 1 Vez </small><br>
<small>* Maximo 2 Vip Por Conta </small><br>
<small>* VIP Valera por 31 Dias </small><br>
<small>* Nao Vendemos Kits Diferentes dos Abaixo </small><br><br>
Apos Wipe <br>
<small>* Kits VIP"s Serao Liberado as 00:00 </small> <br><br>
Ativar Vip <br>
<small>* Apos o Pagamento Aprovado Basta Entrar no Jogo e Digitar<br> /ativarvip (CODIGO DE TRANSACAO) ex <b>9C834542-8123-4419-9A75-BAD63B495EF1</b> </small><br>
<small>* Em Menos de 12 horas Sua Conta sera ativa no <a href="../areavip/site/index.php">(Painel VIP)</a> </small><br>
<hr>
<input type="button" value="Proximo" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="proxima_ir_cadastro_bronze">
</div>';

$cadbronze = '
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
          <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
            <span class="text-muted">Carrinho</span>
            <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">1</span>
          </h4>
          <ul class="list-group mb-3">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
              <div>
                <h6 class="my-0">1x VIP Bronze</h6>
                <small class="text-muted">InsaneRust 4x</small>
              </div>
              <span class="text-muted">R$15,00</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span>Total (BRL)</span>
              <strong>R$15,00</strong>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <form class="card p-2">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Codigo de Promocao">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Usar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
          <h4 class="mb-3">Dados Para o Painel VIP</h4>
          <form class="needs-validation" method="POST" action="modal/p_c_bronze.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label>Seu Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vip_nome" placeholder="Digite seu Nome" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">  Verifique Seu Nome </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label>Seu Nick</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vip_nick" placeholder="Digite Seu Nick do Servidor" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">  Verifique Seu Nick  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label>Seu Email</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="vip_email" placeholder="Digite Seu E-mail" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;"> Confira Seu Email.  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label>Senha</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="vip_senha" placeholder="Escolha uma Senha para o (PainelVIP)" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback"> Confira sua Senha </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label>Sua Steam</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vip_steam" placeholder="Insira a Url da Sua Steam" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback"> Confira sua Steam </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="mb-4">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                  <strong>Informação</strong> <br>Esse cadastro é apenas para acesso na (AREAVIP) e Para Nos Entrar em Contato Sobre Alguma Coisa efetuada/alterada fora isso nao entraremos em contato.
                </div>
            <hr class="mb-4">
            <h4 class="mb-3">Forma de Pagamento</h4>

            <div class="d-block my-3">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" checked required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="credit">PAGSEGURO</label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="debit">PAYPAL</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="mb-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Finalizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>';

$insane->setSaida("corpo_inicio", $html);
$insane->setSaida("boxBronze_cadastro", $cadbronze);
$insane->fim();

?>
```

Comment: You can edit questions after posting them and are encouraged to do that. Instead of adding this code as an answer, edit your question and put the code there, and then delete this answer. And welcome to Stack Overflow! As with anything, it takes a while to learn all the local customs. :-)

Comment: Also, this code doesn't show the key item: which version and flavor of jQuery you are loading. Charlie's guess in a comment above is a likely cause of the problem.